# Should the tags (mathjax) and (tex) on meta be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, mathjax, tag-synonyms, meta

As far as I can tell, both [mathjax](/questions/tagged/mathjax) and [tex](/questions/tagged/tex) are used here on meta for questions about usage of [MathJax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax) in posts on the main site. (AFAICT MathJax is the correct terminology, but unsurprisingly many people know this syntax simply as TeX/LaTeX.) At the moment there are 66 question tagged (mathjax), 31 questions tagged (tex) and 26 questions [have both tags](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathjax+tex).

It is not ideal to have two separate tags for the same topic - for example, it complicates things when searching using tags. So I think these two tags should be synonyms.

I've checked a few other sites [that use MathJax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216606/). On some other metas:

- On Mathematics, (mathjax) has [synonyms](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/mathjax/synonyms) (tex) and (latex), with (mathjax) as the master tag. Similarly [on Computer Science](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/mathjax/synonyms).
- On Meta Stack Exchange, there is [only mathjax tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/mathjax/synonyms). Similarly on [Chemistry](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/mathjax/synonyms), [MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/mathjax/synonyms).
- Electrical Engineering has three separate tags ([tex](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tex)), ([latex](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex)) and ([mathjax](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathjax)).

---

I have [previously asked this in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/13775/2018/5/31). One of the moderators [recommended to ask on meta](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45893222#45893222).

Comment: Perhaps make them synonyms of an umbrella tag 'tex-latex-mathjax'?

Comment: I'd rather not, since strictly speaking TeX and LaTeX are off topic, only Mathjax is on topic here.

Comment: I think most people here call it MathJax; so far I've seen only one person call MathJaxification 'LaTeXification'. The MathSE tutorial which we always direct new users to is called 'MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference', so we shouldn't confuse people by including other related stuff.

Comment: While SE.Physics's most active, involved users probably know the difference between [tag:TeX] and [tag:MathJax], I suspect that many readers aren't aware of the distinction.  Those who have questions about TeX/MathJax, and are therefore searching Meta for information, would seem particularly likely to have confusion about it.  It does seem in users' best interest for the tags to facilitate them finding what they want to know, even if they're fuzzy on how to refer to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I have created a synonym [tex](/questions/tagged/tex)→[mathjax](/questions/tagged/mathjax). The 2 tags are not yet merged, so if the community feels strongly about it one way or another, speak up: It can still be undone.

Comment: The merge looks completely appropriate to me.